# How to teach eclipse custom pre-processor directives?

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, pic

I'm trying to use eclipse CDT IDE for Microchip PIC development using the [CCS C Compiler](http://www.ccsinfo.com/).
Primarily I want to use eclipse CDT as an editor, so I created a makefile project. The makefile just invokes the compiler as makefiles do. This works just fine.

CCS C Compiler uses some non-Standard pre-processor directives like `#device`, `#fuses`, `#asm`, `#org` etc.
The editor adds yellow curly underlines and a question mark to this directives with the hint :"invalid preprocessor directive".
Is there anything I can do, to teach eclipse these custom pre-processor directives? As I said compiling by makefile works fine but the curly underlines bother me.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `#pragma` directive solves the issue. Because the directives I am using are highly compiler related, the `#pragma` is the way to go. Not what I originally wanted, but it works. No warnings and curly underlines are shown anymore.

```c
      #pragma device 16F688
      #pragma fuses INTRC_IO,WDT,PUT,MCLR, ...
```

instead of

```c
      #device 16F688
      #fuses INTRC_IO,WDT,PUT,MCLR, ...
```